# Equivalence relation proof, problem $x∼y \iff x^2 − 2x + 1 = y^2 + 4y + 4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Determine if the following relationships are equivalent. If they are, determine
the equivalence classes, give a set of indices and the quotient set. Sketch out
the graph of each relationship (whether or not it is an equivalence one):
In $\mathbb{R}$, we define the relationship “∼” as
$x ∼ y$ ⇐⇒ $x^2$ − 2x + 1 = $y^2$ + 4y + 4$.
I have a question about transitivity, how can i prove it?
i need to show that x∼z
I tried to do this:

Suppose   $x∼y$ and $y∼z$ thus:
 $x^2$ − 2x + 1 = $y^2$ + 4y + 4   and $y^2$ − 2y + 1 = $z^2$ + 4z + 4.

so we equal to 0 
 $x^2$ − 2x + 1- ($y^2$ + 4y + 4)=0 and
$y^2$ − 2y + 1-($z^2$ + 4z + 4)=0

then we equal the equations:
 $x^2$ − 2x + 1- ($y^2$ + 4y + 4)=$y^2$ − 2y + 1-($z^2$ + 4z + 4)
we resolve and we have :

(( $x^2$ − 2x + 1)+1)+(-$y^2$ + y)+7.5=((-1)($z^2$ + 4z + 4))+(-$y^2$ -y)-7.5

So i think this relation is transitive, but i dont know if i`m good, and i dont have any idea how to make the equivalence classes or set of indices

Comment: $R$ means real numbers (usually denoted $\mathbb R$)?

Comment: yes,excatly, ¡'

Comment: It seems odd to get interested in the transitivity property (the most advanced one of an equivalence relation) when reflexivity (the most basic one) is not even satisfied...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This relation is not transitive.  A single counterexample suffices to prove that.

$x\sim y\iff (x-1)^2=(y+2)^2$.

Can you show $5\sim2$ and $2\sim -3$ but not $5\sim-3$?

Comment: thank you very much, you´re right i saw my mistake, indeed is not transitive relation